# Dataflow Flex Tempates throwing error while run "stat /opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While running the dataflow template in python using the following command

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "streaming-beam-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`" \
    --template-file-gcs-location "$TEMPLATE_PATH" \
    --region "$REGION"
```

The job gets triggered on the console but the DAG is not formed and the following error is reported after a couple of minutes

```
  /usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher\": stat /opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Can someone figure out what the problem could be?

I have already checked the following

1. The template file is present in the location
2. The registry has the image

Not sure what the error means?

Comment: Please provide additional information about your env. Are you running that command from GCP UI or from your local machine? Please provide a scenario how you are running this and where exactly is this template? If you try to run this via GCP UI you also get this issue `Dataflow` > `Jobs` > `Create Job from template`? It's your own template or it's [Google provided template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates)? Could you try a run like mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/run) with parameters?

Comment: Initiating it from local CLI and the docker was created using docker build and push in 2 commands. This was followed by      "gcloud dataflow flex-template build $TEMPLATE_PATH \ ........"

Comment: I cannot replicate this scenario. Could you provide all your steps to get this issue (without private information)? I'd like to replicate it. Could you also replicate this behavior using ready GCP templates?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this.

**Scenario:**
Pipeline runs fine locally while running on DirectRunner.

Job is stuck in queued phased and errors out after a while with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher\": stat /opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

**Solution:**
Using one of the base images from the below link will help. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/flex-templates-base-images

I would recommend to make sure you tick the following checks as well.

1. ENTRYPOINT by default is `["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]` and need not be set explicitly, unless needed, in your Dockerfile. (***When you use one of the base images from the above url***)
2. Ensure that the below params are set in your Dockerfile:

> ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${path}/beam_job.py" ENV
> FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${path}/requirements.txt"

3. I threw in the below params and left them empty just-in-case.

> ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
> ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
> ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE=""

4. Do not set `save_main_session=True` in your pipelineOptions unless explicitly required.
5. Ensure `pipeline.run()` is called in your code.